# "Have our minds made up" vs. "have made up our minds"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This could be a more general question. What is the difference in the meanings of the two following structures?

> 1. Have/has something/somebody + past participle

and

> 2. Have/has + past participle + something/somebody

Or, is there difference between them in any other respect except for their meanings?

examples:

> 1. When we **have made up our minds**, we will go to the party.
> 2. When we **have our minds made up**, we will go to the party.

Answer (score 1):

"have our minds made up" sounds like it has been done by someone else.

Consider "When I've made my bed" vs "When I've had my bed made.".  In the latter case, we assume someone else will be making the bed - a servant perhaps.

Comment: Does "have our minds made up" *exclusively* mean that someone else did it?

Comment: No, that's why I said it "sounds like".  I meant that it would be more likely to be interpreted that way (in my opinion).

Comment: @Sasan: No. For example, you could chivvy your child who's late getting ready for school: *Are you ready yet? Do you have your tie on? Do you have your hair brushed?* In practice that would nearly always be *Have you got your tie on? Have you brushed your hair?,* but syntactically my version is perfectly valid, and *because of the context* it wouldn't normally be understood as implying someone else tied the tie and brushed the hair.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, when the context is appropriate, there is no difference between their meanings, and they differ just in the style of speech,right?

Comment: @Sasan: In principle, yes. But in practice you should stick to "standard" versions (such as *When we have **made up our minds**, we will go* or *When we have **made our minds up,** we will go*), because the alternative sequence will *usually* sound "marked", and as a non-native speaker you've really got very little chance of knowing when it might be "acceptable".